# Lyrics in the Gracenote

Tags: gracenote

How can I get lyric information on a track? I notice all other information is available and I have been reading that gracenote offers lyric database lookup. If this is possible can someone get me on the right path on how to get started or the documentation for this?

I'm using GNSDK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gracenote does not offer Lyrics through the non-commercial program any more.

Comment: But the commercial license exists the possibility of acquiring the lyrics?